# How to turn warnings into errors when building sphinx documentation with setuptools?

Tags: python, python-sphinx, setuptools

I am using setuptools to build my sphinx documentation of a python project (`python setup.py build_sphinx`).

As found on, e.g., [this site](https://webmynd.wordpress.com/2009/01/28/building-sphinx-documentation-with-setuptools/), I have configured the build process using the setup.cfg:

```
[build_sphinx]
source-dir = docs/source
build-dir  = docs/build
all_files  = 1
```

However, I would like to add some more options. Specifically, I would like to turn all warnings into errors, which would work with the `sphinx-build` command with the option `-W`:

```
sphinx-build --help
Sphinx v1.1.3
Usage: /usr/bin/sphinx-build [options] sourcedir outdir [filenames...]
Options: -b <builder> -- builder to use; default is html
         -a        -- write all files; default is to only write new and changed files
         -E        -- don't use a saved environment, always read all files
         -t <tag>  -- include "only" blocks with <tag>
         -d <path> -- path for the cached environment and doctree files
                      (default: outdir/.doctrees)
         -c <path> -- path where configuration file (conf.py) is located
                      (default: same as sourcedir)
         -C        -- use no config file at all, only -D options
         -D <setting=value> -- override a setting in configuration
         -A <name=value>    -- pass a value into the templates, for HTML builder
         -n        -- nit-picky mode, warn about all missing references
         -N        -- do not do colored output
         -q        -- no output on stdout, just warnings on stderr
         -Q        -- no output at all, not even warnings
         -w <file> -- write warnings (and errors) to given file
         -W        -- turn warnings into errors
         -P        -- run Pdb on exception
Modi:
* without -a and without filenames, write new and changed files.
* with -a, write all files.
* with filenames, write these.
```

I do not see a similar option for `python setup.py build_sphinx`:

```
python setup.py build_sphinx --help
Common commands: (see '--help-commands' for more)

  setup.py build      will build the package underneath 'build/'
  setup.py install    will install the package

Global options:
  --verbose (-v)  run verbosely (default)
  --quiet (-q)    run quietly (turns verbosity off)
  --dry-run (-n)  don't actually do anything
  --help (-h)     show detailed help message
  --no-user-cfg   ignore pydistutils.cfg in your home directory

Options for 'BuildDoc' command:
  --fresh-env (-E)   discard saved environment
  --all-files (-a)   build all files
  --source-dir (-s)  Source directory
  --build-dir        Build directory
  --config-dir (-c)  Location of the configuration directory
  --builder (-b)     The builder to use. Defaults to "html"
  --project          The documented project's name
  --version          The short X.Y version
  --release          The full version, including alpha/beta/rc tags
  --today            How to format the current date, used as the replacement
                     for |today|
  --link-index (-i)  Link index.html to the master doc

usage: setup.py [global_opts] cmd1 [cmd1_opts] [cmd2 [cmd2_opts] ...]
   or: setup.py --help [cmd1 cmd2 ...]
   or: setup.py --help-commands
   or: setup.py cmd --help
```

Does anyone know, if turning all warnings into errors can be achieved when building the sphinx docu with setuptools?

Edit:

The option `-W` is not recognized by setuptools:

```
python setup.py build_sphinx -W
usage: setup.py [global_opts] cmd1 [cmd1_opts] [cmd2 [cmd2_opts] ...]
   or: setup.py --help [cmd1 cmd2 ...]
   or: setup.py --help-commands
   or: setup.py cmd --help

error: option -W not recognized
```

Comment: What happens with `python setup.py build_sphinx -W`?

Comment: That argument is [available for `sphinx-build`](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/invocation.html#cmdoption-sphinx-build-W), but apparently can't be set [in `conf.py`](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/config.html) and isn't one of the options your source lists for `[build_sphinx]`. If passing the command line argument explicitly doesn't work, I'd guess it can't be done this way. An alternative might be to look into whether you could use a `cmdclass` in `setup.py`, and specify arguments that way.

Comment: @jonrsharpe: `python setup.py build_sphinx -W` gives an error "option -W not recognized".

Comment: Does it tell you *where* that's not recognised? Is it making it through to Sphinx or failing before it gets there?

Comment: Looks like the setuptools do not recognize the option, see edit.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In [recent versions of Sphinx](https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/blob/1.5/sphinx/setup_command.py#L69-L85), you do this by adding an additional option to the section in `setup.cfg`:

```
[build_sphinx]
all-files = 1
source-dir = docs/source
build-dir = docs/build
warning-is-error = 1
```

Support for this was added in [Sphinx 1.5](https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/commit/a9ffcf0d601b18d1d8e4b9b401a0f04a518b6029), thus, this will not work with older versions.

Comment: How can I put the `warning-is-error = 1` option in Sphinx' `conf.py`?

Comment: I wanted `warning-is-error = 1` for ReadTheDocs, in which case the line `fail_on_warning: True` in the section/variable `sphinx:` in the file `.readthedocs.yml` does the trick.

Answer (score 26):

If instead, like me, you're using `make` to build your html docs with Sphinx, then you can do this to turn warnings into errors and cause `make` to fail:

```
make html SPHINXOPTS="-W"
```

This will cause the build to fail immediately when a warning is encountered. If you add `--keep-going` then the docs build will still fail but it will run to completion so you can see all the warnings. And `-n` will invoke the 'nit-picky' option to check for broken links. So I find this useful when building the docs in my CI framework:

```
make html SPHINXOPTS="-W --keep-going -n"
```

See [here](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/man/sphinx-build.html) for a list of options.

Answer (score 5):

The only solution I can manage is both simple and sub-optimal.

Change from:

```
python setup.py build_sphinx
```

to:

```
python -W error setup.py build_sphinx
```

That will turn **all** warnings into errors, including errors from setuptools, etc., which isn't exactly what you want, but it **will** stop on sphinx errors.

If you're doing this to try and set up Continuous Integration or something, maybe this is good enough?

**UPDATE:** See [stephenfin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42426616/134391) if using Sphinx 1.5+