# See all warnings as errors when building Sphinx docs on readthedocs.org

Tags: python-3.x, python-sphinx, read-the-docs

Our open-source Python project ([PyAbel](https://github.com/PyAbel/PyAbel)) uses readthedocs.org to automatically build the documentation for each pull request using Sphinx. We would like the doc build to fail if there are any warnings from Sphinx, since these usually indicate that some part of the documentation isn't building correctly.

Currently, we are including `sphinx: fail_on_warning: true` in our .readthedocs.yml file. This causes the Sphinx build to fail on the first warning. So far, so good!

However, on my local computer, I can use

```
make html SPHINXOPTS="-W --keep-going"
```

to allow the build to run to completion (thereby showing all the warnings) and then fail, as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38048945/how-to-turn-warnings-into-errors-when-building-sphinx-documentation-with-setupto/59897351#59897351). (Alternatively, I can include `SPHINXOPTS="-W --keep-going"` in the doc/Makefile to achieve the same result.)

This behavior seems like the better option, since we get to see all of the warnings that we need to fix, and the build still fails, so we know that we need to fix them. But, I cannot figure out how to achieve this when the documentation is built on readthedocs.org. While building Sphinx docs on readthedocs.org is there a way that we can see **all** the warnings from the Sphinx build and then still raise an error?

Some related discussion is [here](https://github.com/PyAbel/PyAbel/pull/271#issuecomment-581742733).

Answer (score 1):

According to the [readthedocs documentation](https://docs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config-file/v2.html#sphinx-fail-on-warning), setting `fail_on_warning: true` is currently equivalent to enabling both the `-W` and `--keep-going` flags:

> #### sphinx.fail_on_warning
>
> Turn warnings into errors (`-W` and `--keep-going` options). This means the build fails if there is a warning and exits with exit status 1.

Answer (score 0):

The existing answer focuses on Unix, but does not cover Windows.

If using the `make.bat` on Windows, you must edit the file in two places.

First, adding the `SPHINXOPTS` variable, then modifying the exit behavior of the `sphinx-build` command.

```
set SOURCEDIR=source
set BUILDDIR=build
set "SPHINXOPTS=-W --keep-going"

...

%SPHINXBUILD% -M %1 %SOURCEDIR% %BUILDDIR% %SPHINXOPTS% %O% || exit /b %ERRORLEVEL%
goto end

...
```